# How to share variables across packages in go-lang

Tags: go

I have written a simple go application and formatted it in to several packages.

```
+main
+controllers
+handlers
+commons
+utils
```

I'm starting the server in main package and reading server specific parameters at the startup.

I won't to use those parameters, such as DB properties from commons package. I cannot import main package in to commons 'cause commons is a dependency to controllers, handlers which is a dependency to main. So this causes cyclic import.

How should we handle this kind of situation?. Is it possible to read the configuration once and refer to it inside commons package whenever needed? Example would be helpful.

Comment: Choose a package which doesn't import your other packages, so all your packages can import it. And place shared variables into it. And the `main` package can also access it to store parameters read on startup.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have that many separate packages for a single go application. There's been a lot of chatter in the go community about this over the years, but you're probably better off, for a binary, with a dominant package main, only seperating out other packages that you clearly expect to reuse in a different project. Here's some further [discussion](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/organizing-go-code/1110/6) on this point.

Comment: Assuming you follow AndrewN's advice (KISS), and avoid extra package structure for now, can you just read the parameters from the command line using the flag package? That would seem to solve the problem as described. AFAIK, the flag package can be called from any package (isn't Go lovely?), not just main, so if it is critical that parameters are in a shared package, but not main, do the work from there.

Comment: ... Or, can you read the parameters from the environment `os.Environ()`? Again, they can be read from any package.

Comment: Reading parameters from flag or os.Environ() would not be scalable once  we have many configurations. What I'm using now is a config.yaml and use viper to read them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a config package and when you need to use a config variable then you can send to another struct into different package.

```
main() {
    config := config{}
    user = NewUser(config)
    ...
}
```

I recommend to you check the config revel package (https://github.com/revel/config). It's used into revel framework [https://github.com/revel/revel](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/revel/revel@master/.tree/config.go).

Comment: Is revel solving a different, more sophisticated problem? Just because there is a 'sledge hammer', we don't need to use it :-)